# Grid Container resize with height and width specified - C# WPF Anchoring

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When using Margins to specify top/left/bottom/right positions, the location of my button and inner grids is not what I expected with the following xaml:

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    Title="Dialog" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"  ResizeMode="CanResize" Height="399" Width="590">

<Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"  x:Name="TopÆLeftÆRight596" Background="#FFFFFF">
    <Grid Margin="150, 85, 153, 110" x:Name="Panel597" Background="#EEEEEE">
        <Button Margin="97,77,108,101" x:Name="BLANK_BUTTON598" ToolTip="Blank" Cursor="Arrow" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="#000000" Content="Blank"  />
    </Grid>      
</Grid>
```

I believe what is happening is that because my container grid is set to stretch (x:Name="TopÆLeftÆRight596"), the margins are calculated off the window which includes the title bar.  If I set height and width on that grid, resizing of the inner controls is no longer possible.

I need a way to specify the height/width values on the window, or perhaps another type of container, so that the margin calculations do not include the title bar, and the inner contents grow and shrink when the window is resized.

Please keep in mind I have no control over the left/top/right/bottom margin values provided.

In essence, what I'm trying to do is duplicate top/left/bottom/right anchoring of the Grid(x:Name="Panel597") and Button(x:Name="BLANK_BUTTON598") controls.

Any help is greatly appreciate.  Thanks.

Comment: The title bar is not included in the calculation. I don't really get what is the problem here, it works as expected. Outer grid occupies the whole client area of the window (no title bar included), the inner grid occupies the area of the outer grid minus margins you provided. And the inner button occupies the inner grid's area minus the margin you provided. Also it resizes as you resize the window.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  My issue can be illustrated by removing the Height and Width properties from the window and placing them in the outer grid (x:Name="TopÆLeftÆRight596").  Notice how the button displays after doing this?  If the title bar isn't included in the calculation, why the difference?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your window ? Just from your explanation I cannot understand what is your problem.